# Extract dictionary value from a list with one element in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column which is a list containing a single dictionary.
For example:

```
col1
[{'type': 'yellow', 'id': 2, ...}]
[{'type': 'brown', 'id': 13, ...}]
...
```

I need to extract the value associated with the 'type' keyword. There are different ways to do it, but since my dataframe is huge (several million rows) I need an efficient way to do this but I am not sure which method is the best.

Comment: Implement the "different ways", and benchmark them with maybe 100000 or 1 million rows?

Comment: Your best bet (and might be the only way) is loop, e.g. `df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x[0].get('type'))`.

Comment: Thanks Quang Hoang, one related question: when I apply your solution I get "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable". Do you have any idea why? I have to add that my col1 contains sometimes NaNs but I can't figure out whether this is related to the error I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try this:

```
data = {
    'col': [[{'type': 'yellow', 'id': 2}], [{'type': 'brown', 'id': 13}], np.nan]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

    col
0   [{'type': 'yellow', 'id': 2}]
1   [{'type': 'brown', 'id': 13}]
2   NaN
```

Use `explode` and `str` accessor:

```
df['result'] = df.col.explode().str['type']
```

output:

```
    col                             result
0   [{'type': 'yellow', 'id': 2}]   yellow
1   [{'type': 'brown', 'id': 13}]   brown
2   NaN                              NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing any element in most data structures is O(1) operation. I'm sure pandas data frame is no different. The only issue you will face is: looping through the rows. There's probably no way around it.